# SQL - Return column1 and max of column2 when column 1 has multiple entries

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with account numbers and dates (amoung other columns). For each account number there are multiple entries with different dates. I want to return only the row with the most recent date and only account numbers that I have from another source.

This is what I've tried but I understand why this doesn't work. I just can't think of an alternative approach.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, MAX(DATE) FROM PORTFOLIO
WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER IN (444347, 899999,
887111,
220922)
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER
```

Comment: What is wrong in the results that you are getting from your current query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, DATE
FROM PORTFOLIO
WHERE ACCOUNT_NUMBER IN (444347, 899999, 887111, 220922)
    and date = (select max(date) from portfolio b where portfolio.account_number = account_number)
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to return only the row with the most recent date and only account numbers that I have from another source.

I understand that you want the latest record per account number. If so, one solution is to use analytic functions:

```
select *
from (
    select
        p.*,
        rank() over(partition by account_number order by date desc) rn
    from portfolio p
    where account_number in (444347, 899999, 887111, 220922)
) t
where rn = 1
```

Another approach uses a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select p.*
from portfolio p
where 
    p.account_number in (444347, 899999, 887111, 220922)    
    and p.date = (
        select max(p1.date) from portfolio p1 where p1.account_number = p.account_number
    )
```

Comment: Your suspicions are correct. Your methods are a little more advanced than I am comfortable with but I will study them. Thank you... Preacher had a more elegant solution.

Comment: @nicodemusmd: let me pinpoint that the other solution is exactly the same as the second query in my answer - and it was posted afterwards.

Comment: lol, I see. I saw his query before I realized you had two of them.